# use extension or implementation for an online system

Tags: java, oop

I try to create a system that allows me to inherit from on class to another.
However, do I use implement or extend for this program?

```
public String search(bikeString product)
    {
      public class Customer extends Product
{ 
    private String bikeoName = "";
    private int bikeIdNo = "";
    private int price = "";





}
```

Answer (score 0):

`extends` is for extending a class. More specifically **extends** is the keyword used to inherit the properties of a class.

`implements` is for implementing an interface. This is used to implement an interface (parent class with functions signatures only but not their definitions) by defining it in the child class.

**extends:**

```
public class Vehicle {
    //properties and methods
}
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    //new properties and methods
}
```

**implements:**

```
public interface A {
    //stuff you want to put
}
public class B implements A {
    //your class code
}
```